# Azure Container Registry Permissions

Tags: azure, docker

Im trying to setup simple read only access using Azure AD to an Azure container registry.

I have managed to setup a service principal with read only access no problem, but when creating an AD account and using IAM on the registry I cannot login using az acr.

I have created an account in Azure AD, added is to the registry IAM, assigned it reader role (this matches the role given to the service principal) but receive the following error logging in with az acr

```
The client 'xxxx@xxxxxx.co.uk' with object id 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/listCredentials/action' over scope '/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/xxxxxxxxxxxx'.
```

The only way I can get logged in using the az acr is to assign IAM contributor permissions on the resource group.

Is there something im missing?

tia

Answer (score 1):

It is a RBAC issue.

Could you please try to use this `docker login` to login ACR?

You can also log in directly with a `service principal`. Provide the **app ID** and **password** of the service principal to the docker login command:

```
 docker login myregistry.azurecr.io -u xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx -p myPassword
```

When you log in with `az acr login`, the CLI uses the **token** created when you executed `az login` to seamlessly authenticate your session with your registry.

Please check your service principal permission, also you can create a new service principal and assign to this **group**.

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "http://my-app" --role reader --scopes /subscriptions/11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555/resourceGroups/mygroup
```

The available roles are:

**Reader**: pull
**Contributor**: pull and push
**Owner**: pull, push, and assign roles to other users

Note:

When you use `az acr login` to login acr, this command will use the token created when you executed `az login` to login it. This token **not** equal to your service principal(reader).

Comment: The issue isn't with the SP, i can login using this using docker login and the correct permissions are assigned. Im not using a headless system so need az ad to control permissions for individuals.

The individuals can login if they have contributor access to the resource group, but this role is too high, they need read only access

Comment: @user2638540 Have you grant permission to that resource group?

Comment: yes - they can only access the container registry if they have owner access to the resource group

Comment: @user2638540 Could you please create a new user for test, grant read role to that new account and test again. Read permission works for me.